# Uploading Image to Azure Blob using File Uploader in ASP.NET?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, azure, azure-storage

I need to allow a user to specify an image that needs to be uploaded to the Azure DB instead of hard coding the Image Path like all the tutorials out there. This is what I have so far:

```
<asp:FileUpload ID="imageUploader" runat="server" />
<asp:Button ID="uploadBtn" runat="server" Text="Upload Image" class="btn btn-success btn-sm" OnClick="uploadBtn_Click" />
```

Code:

```
CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["StorageConnectionString"]);
CloudBlobClient blobClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();

 // Retrieve a reference to a container. 
CloudBlobContainer container = blobClient.GetContainerReference("pictures");

// Create the container if it doesn't already exist.
container.CreateIfNotExists();
container.SetPermissions(new BlobContainerPermissions
{
        PublicAccess = BlobContainerPublicAccessType.Blob
});

CloudBlockBlob blockBlob = container.GetBlockBlobReference("myblob");

blockBlob.UploadFromFile(imageUploader.PostedFile.FileName, FileMode.Open);
```

However this doesn't seem to work. How can I upload an image to azure using a File Uploader in ASP.NET?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `UploadFromFile` is using the wrong parameter. See Microsoft [CloudBlockBlob.UploadFromFile](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.windowsazure.storage.blob.cloudblockblob.uploadfromfile.aspx). The first parameter should be a file path i.e. `C:\Users\etc...` not just the name of the file that you are parsing `imageUploader.PostedFile.FileName`.

You most likely want to be using `UploadFromStream` like this:

```
blockBlob.UploadFromStream(imageUploader.PostedFile.InputStream);
```

You should check the documentation for [CloudBlockBlob](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.windowsazure.storage.blob.cloudblockblob_members.aspx) as there are a number of different upload methods.

Comment: Hmmm it shows an error when I use that code Ashley:

'System.Web.HttpPostedFile' does not contain a definition for 'FileContent' and no extension method 'FileContent' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Web.HttpPostedFile' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)